# Can I determine which Submit button was used in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a very simple form with a name field and two submit buttons: 'change' and 'delete'. I need to do some form validation in javascript when the form is submitted so I need to know which button was clicked. If the user hits the enter key, the 'change' value is the one that makes it to the server. So really, I just need to know if the 'delete' button was clicked or not.

Can I determine which button was clicked? Or do I need to change the 'delete' button from a submit to a regular button and catch its onclick event to submit the form?

The form looks like this:

```
 <form action="update.php" method="post" onsubmit="return checkForm(this);">
    <input type="text" name="tagName" size="30" value="name goes here" />
    <input type="hidden" name="tagID" value="1" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Change" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete" />
 </form>
```

In the `checkForm()` function, `form["submit"]` is a node list, not a single element I can grab the value of.

Comment: people, please don't randomly vote down answers without leaving a comment...

Comment: It looks like someone went through and down-voted most of the answers without any explanation.

Comment: Downvoting without commenting is just cowardly.  Looks like someone was bored more than they had a problem with the answers, everyone here has at least a -1.

Comment: As per answer by @valentin, the way to do this in 2022 is `event.submitter`. Simple and elegant and doesn't need loading a 92kB library to do it (which is rarely the proper way to answer a question here unless specifically asked for it)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could also use the `onclick` event in a number of different ways to address the problem.

For instance:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete" 
       onclick="return TryingToDelete();" />
```

In the `TryingToDelete()` function in JavaScript, do what you want, then `return false` if do not want the delete to proceed.

Comment: Great! One does not need to tie the function call to the form; it also works on the buttons.

Comment: This question and answer are both over 3 years old now. Today, I would use JQuery and bind events to the buttons. However, this approach still works if you aren't doing much javascript on the page.

Comment: There was far more reason to use jQuery 3 years ago than there is today.

Answer (score 14):

Here's an **unobtrusive approach** using jQuery...

```
$(function ()
{
    // for each form on the page...
    $("form").each(function ()
    {
        var that = $(this); // define context and reference

        /* for each of the submit-inputs - in each of the forms on
           the page - assign click and keypress event */
        $("input:submit", that).bind("click keypress", function ()
        {
            // store the id of the submit-input on it's enclosing form
            that.data("callerid", this.id);
        });
    });


    // assign submit-event to all forms on the page
    $("form").submit(function ()
    {
        /* retrieve the id of the input that was clicked, stored on
           it's enclosing form */
        var callerId = $(this).data("callerid");

        // determine appropriate action(s)
        if (callerId == "delete") // do stuff...

        if (callerId == "change") // do stuff...

        /* note: you can return false to prevent the default behavior
           of the form--that is; stop the page from submitting */ 
    });
});
```

**Note:** this code is using the id-property to reference elements, so you have to update your markup. If you want me to update the code in my answer to make use of the name-attribute to determine appropriate actions, let me know.

Answer (score 7):

Some browsers (at least Firefox, Opera and IE) support this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkForm(form, event) {
    // Firefox || Opera || IE || unsupported
    var target = event.explicitOriginalTarget || event.relatedTarget ||
        document.activeElement || {};

    alert(target.type + ' ' + target.value);
    return false;
}
</script>
<form action="update.php" method="post" onsubmit="return checkForm(this, event);">
   <input type="text" name="tagName" size="30" value="name goes here" />
   <input type="hidden" name="tagID" value="1" />
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Change" />
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete" />
</form>
```

For an inherently cross-browser solution, you'll have to add `onclick` handlers to the buttons themselves.

Comment: document.activeElement works in chrome, firefox, opera, IE8, IE9, and IE11. event.explicitOriginalTarget also works in firefox. i cant check safari but it is based on chrome now days so id assume it works like chrome

Comment: Do not assume a button was clicked, it could have been enter being pressed on a text field, check `target.type` in addition to `target.value`

Comment: Alas, this doesn't work on Safari, `document.activeElement` is body. See [more comparisons here](https://zellwk.com/blog/inconsistent-button-behavior/).

Answer (score 5):

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
var submit;
function checkForm(form)
{
alert(submit.value);
return false;
}

function Clicked(button)
{
  submit= button ;
}
</script>
<body>
 <form method="post" onsubmit="return checkForm(this);">
    <input type="text" name="tagName" size="30" value="name goes here" />
    <input type="hidden" name="tagID" value="1" />
    <input onclick="Clicked(this);" type="submit" name="submit" value="Change" />
    <input onclick="Clicked(this);" type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete" />
 </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @ps: drive-by-voting; stylistic issues aside, there's nothing wrong with your answer - apart from the fact that it doesn't handle the case when the user submits the form by pressing enter in the text field in IE (IE won't use a submit button for this, but other browsers do)

Comment: the OP asked a very specific question. 
"So really, I just need to know if the 'delete' button was clicked or not.

Can I determine which button was clicked?"

 and i answered that question. :)

Answer (score 5):

You could use the [`SubmitEvent.submitter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubmitEvent/submitter) property.

```js
form.addEventListener('submit', event => console.log(event.submitter))
```

Comment: While browser support for this may have been low in 2010, this is now THE way to do this. Simple and elegant, and certainly much easier than loading a 92kB js library to do it

Answer (score 1):

Give each of the buttons a unique ID such as

```
<input type="submit" id="submitButton" name="submit" value="Change" />
<input type="submit" id="deleteButton" name="submit" value="Delete" />
```

I'm not sure how to do this in raw javascript but in jquery you can then do

```
$('#submitButton').click(function() {
  //do something
});
$('#deleteButton').click(function() {
  //do something
});
```

This says that if submitButton is clicked, do whatever is inside it.
if deleteButton is clicked, do whatever is inside it

Comment: You can grab elements based on their id's and perform operations on them.

Comment: Will one of those operations tell me whether the button was clicked?

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery you can use $.data() to keep data in scope - no need for global variables in that case.
First you click submit button, then (depending on it's action) you assign data to form. I'm not preventing default action in click event, so form is submitted right after click event ends.

HTML:

```
<form action="update.php" method="post"">
    <input type="text" name="tagName" size="30" value="name goes here" />
    <input type="hidden" name="tagID" value="1" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Change" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete" />
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
 (function ($) {
        "use strict";
        $(document).ready(function () {

            // click on submit button with action "Change"
            $('input[value="Change"]').on("click", function () {
                var $form = $(this).parents('form');
                $form.data("action", "Change");
            });

            // click on submit button with action "Delete"
            $('input[value="Delete"]').on("click", function () {
                var $form = $(this).parents('form');
                $form.data("action", "Delete");
            });

            // on form submit
            $('form').on("submit", function () {
                var $self = $(this);

                // retrieve action type from form
                // If there is none assigned, go for the default one
                var action = $self.data("action") || "deafult";

                // remove data so next time you won't trigger wrong action
                $self.removeData("action");

                // do sth depending on action type
                if (action === "change") {
                }
            });
        });
    })(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now you've got the same problem as you would a normal text input. You've got the same name on two different elements. Change the names to "Change" and "Delete" and then determine if either one of them were clicked by applying an event handler on both submits and providing different methods. I'm assuming you're using pure JavaScript, but if you want it to be quick, take a look at jQuery.

What you need is as simple as following what's on [w3schools](http://w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't mention using any framework, this is the cleanest way to do it with straight Javascript. With this code what you're doing is passing the button object itself into the go() function.  You then have access to all of the button's properties.  You don't have to do anything with setTimeout(0) or any other wacky functions.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function go(button) {
        if (button.id = 'submit1')
            //do something
        else if (button.id = 'submit2')
            //do something else
    }
</script>

<form action="update.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="tagName" size="30" value="name goes here" />
    <input type="hidden" name="tagID" value="1" />
    <input id="submit1" type="submit" name="submit" value="Change" onclick="go(this);"/>
    <input id="submit2" type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete" onclick="go(this);"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

A `click` event anywhere in a form will be caught by a form's `click` handler (as long as the element clicked on allows it to propagate). It will be processed before the form's `submit` event.

Therefore, one can test whether the click target was an `input` (or `button`) tag of the `submit` type, and save the value of it (say, to a `data-button` attribute on the form) for processing in the form's `submit` handler.

The submit buttons themselves do not then need any event handlers.

I needed to do this to change a form's `action` and `target` attributes, depending upon which submit button is clicked.

```js
// TO CAPTURE THE BUTTON CLICKED    
function get_button(){
 var oElement=event.target;
 var oForm=oElement.form;
 
 // IF SUBMIT INPUT BUTTON (CHANGE 'INPUT' TO 'BUTTON' IF USING THAT TAG)
 if((oElement.tagName=='INPUT')&&(oElement.type=='submit')){
  // SAVE THE ACTION
  oForm.setAttribute('data-button',oElement.value);
 }
}

// TO DO THE SUBMIT PROCESSING    
function submit_form(){
 var oForm=event.target;

 // RETRIEVE THE BUTTON CLICKED, IF ONE WAS USED     
 var sAction='';
 if(oForm.hasAttribute('data-button')){
  // SAVE THE BUTTON, THEN DELETE THE ATTRIBUTE (SO NOT USED ON ANOTHER SUBMIT)     
  sAction=oForm.getAttribute('data-button');
  oForm.removeAttribute('data-button');
 }

 // PROCESS BY THE BUTTON USED     
 switch(sAction){
  case'Change':
   // WHATEVER
   alert('Change');
   break;
  case'Delete':
   // WHATEVER
   alert('Delete');
   break;
  default:
   // WHATEVER FOR ENTER PRESSED
   alert('submit: By other means');
   break;
 }
}
```

```html
 <form action="update.php" method="post" onsubmit="submit_form();" onclick="get_button();">
    <input type="text" name="tagName" size="30" value="name goes here" />
    <input type="hidden" name="tagID" value="1" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Change" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete" />
 </form>
 <p id="result"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:
Just add dataset in submit button like this:

```
<form action="update.php" method="post" onsubmit="return checkForm(this);">
    <input type="text" name="tagName" size="30" value="name goes here" />
    <input type="hidden" name="tagID" value="1" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Change" data-clicked="change" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete" data-clicked="delete" />
</form>
```

In JS access it by:

```
$('body').on("submit", function(event){
  var target = event.explicitOriginalTarget || event.relatedTarget || document.activeElement || {};
  var buttonClicked = target.dataset['clicked'];
  console.log(buttonClicked);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Name the delete button something else. Perhaps name one SubmitChange and name the other SubmitDelete.

Comment: This wouldn't help. As far as I observe, the value of the submit button isn't transmitted when the form is submitted.

Comment: The value of the submit button is transmitted when pressed/clicked. If isn't present the default submit button was pressed, probably by pressing enter on one of the form entry fields.

Comment: How does the name change help me determine which was clicked? I need to know in javascript, not on the update.php page.

Comment: That's true. My answer merely helps you with the conflicting names. What you'll probably want to do is change each submit button to a regular type="button" button. Assign an onclick to each of those, and inside their respective onclick handlers call document.forms["formname"].submit();

Comment: I don't recommend this - it would break the page if JS is disabled

Answer (score -1):

I've been dealing with this problem myself. There's no built-in way to tell which button's submitting a form, but it's a feature which might show up in the future.

The workaround I use in production is to store the button somewhere for one event loop on click. The JavaScript could look something like this:

```
function grabSubmitter(input){
    input.form.submitter = input;
    setTimeout(function(){
        input.form.submitter = null;
    }, 0);
}
```

... and you'd set an onclick on each button:

```
<input type="submit" name="name" value="value" onclick="grabSubmitter(this)">
```

`click` fires before `submit`, so in your submit event, if there's a submitter on your form, a button was clicked.

---

I'm using jQuery, so I use `$.fn.data()` instead of expando to store the submitter. I have a tiny plugin to handle temporarily setting data on an element that looks like this:

```
$.fn.briefData = function(key, value){
        var $el = this;
        $el.data(key, value);
        setTimeout(function(){
            $el.removeData(key);
        }, 0);
    };
```

and I attach it to buttons like this:

```
$(':button, :submit').live('click', function () {
    var $form = $(this.form);
    if ($form.length) {
        $form.briefData('submitter', this);
    }
});
```