# How to get the ID of a dynamic element when clicked?

Tags: javascript, element, click

I have a simple html file upload form, it's something like this:

```
<form action="upload_file.php" id="theForm" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Files:</label>
<input type="file" name="file[]" id="file1"><button id="rem1" type="button">Remove File</button>
...
...    
<input type="file" name="file[]" id="file99"><button id="rem99" type="button">Remove     File</button>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The inputs are created dynamically. I need to know the id of the button which was clicked.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I determine which Submit button was used in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298635/can-i-determine-which-submit-button-was-used-in-javascript)

Comment: With jQuery, you can [use the `.on()` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) which delegates to dynamically created elements.

Comment: There is no "click handler" in the presented code. Please include an *actual* example case. This is why I have given a -1: the post *must* represent the problem!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using jQuery this should make you happy:

```
// delegate click event to all button elements in #theForm;
// will also apply for buttons added in future
$('#theForm').on('click', 'button', function(e) {
   alert(e.target.id);
});
```

if not, attach this to each button:

```
blablabla.onclick = function(event){
    alert(event.currentTarget.id);
}
```

Comment: `this` is more concise but it also may be confusing, because event is attached to parent node and triggered by element inside (target).

Answer (score 4):

Get each input with javascript, attach the click event listener to each, then in the click function, use `this.id`. [Live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/OqAjAGE/1/edit)

```
  <button id="foo">Button</button>
  <button id="bar">Button</button>
  <button id="baz">Button</button>
  <button id="qux">Button</button>
```

and the js:

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

for (var i=0; i<buttons.length; ++i) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click', clickFunc);
}

function clickFunc() {
  alert(this.id); 
}
```

Comment: If you decide to do it this way, be sure you are adding this vanilla JS snippet of code **AFTER** the inputs are dynamically created (in the same block of code).

Comment: @DevlshOne what a comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your question requests a javascript answer. If you are alright with using jQuery, then you can solve your problem like this.

If not, then perhaps this answer will give you hints on where to search. It has to do with binding the click event to the new DOM elements. -- **Nevermind on that, m59 has created an excellent answer in pure js.**

If the element has been dynamically created, you must use jQuery's `.on()` method. Then, you can:

```
$(document).on('click', 'file999', function() {
    var i = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(i);
});
```

Note that to use jQuery you must include the jQuery library in the `<head>` tags, thus:

```
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have created two buttons that change the div demo value according to the button `innerHTML`.

I hope this helps.

```html
<button class="btn" type="button" name="button" id="btn_1">1</button>
<button class="btn" type="button" name="button" id="btn_2">2</button>
<div id="demo">
  hello
</div>
<script>
  var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');
  for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
    btn[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
    });
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

The Cssyphus answer worked for me but you need to add '#' before `file999`.

Answer (score -2):

Get your button to be generated with something like this:

```
<input type="file" name="file[]" id="file1"><button id="rem1" type="button" onclick="myfunction('file1')">Remove File</button>
```

javascript:

```
function myfunction(inputId){
    //do the thing
}
```

Comment: Goodness. Stop with the inline js. Stop.

Comment: Why, do u know if he needs to directly use a function or not? using event listener may not be the better solution for him, he may want to get the file if so this is the easiest way to get that

Comment: I have no idea what you just said. I am saying STOP using inline js. That's been bad practice for years. `onlick` in your html is never the right thing to do.